# PHP: How to get rid of � symbol inside text?

Tags: regex

Can't figure out, how to remove this � symbol from string.

String is in utf-8 format.

What to do? :(

This removes whole string:

```
preg_replace('/\W/','',utf8_decode(substr(utf8_encode($ad['description']),0,125)))
```

Thanks ;)

**Update:**

Using:
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

After replacement using exit() right away.

Comment: What's the source of the ad['description'] string?  And what character set is it encoded with?

Comment: Remember to use the `/u` modifier if applying regexes to Unicode strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER is used when the character does not have a representation in the current charset encoding. Declare your encodings properly as UTF-8 and use UTF-8 strings and it will not show upon most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your string is *not* in utf-8 format. You pretend it is, and handle the data accordingly, but the string probably contains Ansi characters. You don't just need to pass the `Content-Encoding = utf-8` header, but your contents needs to be converted to utf-8 before it is sent as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could try utf8_decode('string'); or utf8_encode('string');

but you should really try to find the actuall problem make sure the headers are correct set, document type and that the text is encoded in the right format when saved or what not